# iphonesdk appending string issue

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, nsstring

i have a nsmutablearray which have 5 objects.

for example if it contain objects like apple, cat , ball, dog ,ant, i want them to append with comma separated that is like apple, cat , ball, dog ,ant. please help me with this.

**edit**

```
publishingpost //nsmutable array contains all these object

-(ibaction)post
{
nsstring *str;
nsstring *str2 =@",";
for(int i = 0; i< [publishingpost count]; i++){
nsstring *str = [publishingpost objectAtIndex:i];
//append both str1, str2 to generate comma separated objects

}
```

Comment: This question is somewhat confusing, Faraz. Would it be possible to edit it to re-word it so the question will be clear?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

use `- (NSString *)componentsJoinedByString:(NSString *)separator` instead:

```
- (IBAction)post {
   NSString * str = [publishingpost componentsJoinedByString:@", "];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at `stringByAppendingString:` or `stringByAppendingFormat` from [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html). It should be easy enough to do if you already have the Strings.

Declare an NSString object before the for loop (or use `str`) and append to that while going through the loop. And you're not supposed to declare `str` twice in your code. Might want to rename one of them.